# MYSQL Error in XAMPP server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I Installed XAMPP server(xampp-win32-1.8.3-4-VC11-installer.exe) in windwos 7 64 bit machine.

First changed the Apache port to `Listen 81`. So that's fine.

As I have seperately installed MYSQL in the same machine, changed the PORT to 3307 `[port= 3307]` in my.ini configuration file.

So now my XAMPP control panel looks like following screenshot

[image]

When I check the status it says MySql database status as "Deactivated" even when MySql have started from control panel.

[image]

Also not allowing me to access to **phpmyadmin** and giving me the following Error message...

[image]

Does anybody know where I am going wrong.... Thanks

**Edits**

The values modified (in "my.ini" configuration file) when changing mysql port number is highlighted in the following screenshot. (Values changed to 3307 from default 3306)

[image]

Comment: Did you read "Some changes to the configuration may sometimes cause false negatives." below the status table?

Comment: In other words: **Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**. Wrong password?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario, That was just a test done by changing password to check if it works according to a solution explained in a tutorial. I removed not to have password and still the same.... I just updated it with that screenshot now. Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use the clipboard to copy the error message? It's hard to spot anything in those rescaled pictures. Whatever: you have a pretty good hint that MySQL is running: it returns error messages!

Comment: I am confused as haven't set any password and all others are default settings except the PORT numbers I changed as explaibned in the question. This is what in the message.  ---------> "phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server." -----------------

Comment: @ VMai. That's all in the screen and nothing below that message under the satus table.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your MySQL password. The easiest way is to use the security console, which you can access at `http://localhost/security/` This console creates a password for the MySQL user root and adjusts the phpMyAdmin configuration.

Another approach is to configure it with the "XAMPP Shell" (command prompt). Open the shell and execute this command:
`mysqladmin.exe -u root password secret`

Or you could try to think on moving to Linux or Mac ;)

Comment: I will check this out to see how it goes. Thanks